# Application crash on glColor4f OpenGl function in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv, opengl-es, qcar-sdk

I am working on OpenCV client app, my application works fine on IOS 5.1 but when i run my application on IOS 4.3 then it crashed at `glColor4f` function which defined in `gl.h` class, but it not show any error message on crash. I am doing like following:

```
QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewProjection;


                glColor4f(0.5f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                ShaderUtils::multiplyMatrix(&qUtils.projectionMatrix.data[0], &modelViewMatrix.data[0], &modelViewProjection.data[0]);
                glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
                glVertexAttribPointer(vertexHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (const GLvoid*) &vbVertices[0]);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
                glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandle, 1, GL_FALSE, (GLfloat*)&modelViewProjection.data[0] );
                glColor4f(0.5f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);

                glEnableClientState (GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
                glEnableClientState (GL_COLOR_ARRAY); 
                glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);    
              //  glColorPointer(4, GL_FLOAT, 0, triangleColors);  
                glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (const GLvoid*) &vbVertices[0]); 
                glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
                glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 8);
                //glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
                //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
                glDisableVertexAttribArray(vertexHandle);
```

Comment: I would test the 3 parameter version: `glColor3f(0.5f,0.0f,0.0f)` and see if that also crashes.

Comment: Thanks Karlphillip, but in my this function is unknown should i add header file for this?

Comment: My apologies, `glColor3f()` does not exist in OpenGL ES.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some research and here's a couple of things for you to try:

- Experiment the `glColor4d()`instead, which takes 4 double parameters;
- [You might be calling a null function pointer, hence the crash](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179026-Application-crash-on-glColor4f). That happens when the load procedure doesn't call `getProc` for `glColor4f`;
- Try calling glGetError() before `glColor4f()` to know if there are problem on the GL side of things.

Also, someone replied your question in [this thread](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/179026-Application-crash-on-glColor4f). He might be right.

Answer (score 1):

`glColor4f()` is only used with the OpenGL ES 1.1 fixed function pipeline. From the use of `glUseProgram()` in your above code, you're working in OpenGL ES 2.0, therefore `glColor4f()` is not supported.

If you wish to set the color of your materials, you will need to do that via a uniform in your shader program. If you instead want to just set the background color of your scene, you'd use something like the following:

```
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```